# Unable to get the output as properly formatted dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, web-scraping

I've written a scraper in python to parse some data from a webpage. My intention is to store the data in dictionary. Instead of demonstrating the full table I just tried with a single `tr` containing the information of a single player. The data are coming through but the format of the output is not how dictionary looks like. Any help to make it accurate will be highly appreciated.

This is my try:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://fantasy.premierleague.com/player-list/"

def get_data(link):
    res = requests.get(link,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    data = []
    for content in soup.select("div.ism-container"):
        itmval = {}
        itmval['name'] = content.select_one("h2").text
        itmval['player_info'] = [[item.get_text(strip=True) for item in items.select("td")] for items in content.select(" table:nth-of-type(1) tr:nth-of-type(2)")]
        data.append(itmval)

    print(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_data(URL)
```

The output I'm having:

```
[{'name': 'Goalkeepers', 'player_info': [['De Gea', 'Man Utd', '161', '£5.9']]}]
```

The output I expect to have:

```
[{'name': 'Goalkeepers', 'player_info': ['De Gea', 'Man Utd', '161', '£5.9']}]
```

Btw, I intend to parse the full table but I showed here a minimum portion for your well obseration.

Comment: `itmval['player_info'] = [[item.get_text(strip=True) for item in items.select("td")] for items in content.select(" table:nth-of-type(1) tr:nth-of-type(2)")]` this creates a list of lists. So that's expected. You wanted to flatten the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use nested list comprehension, try to replace

```
[[item.get_text(strip=True) for item in items.select("td")] for items in content.select(" table:nth-of-type(1) tr:nth-of-type(2)")]
```

with

```
[item.get_text(strip=True) for items in content.select(" table:nth-of-type(1) tr:nth-of-type(2)") for item in items.select("td")]
```

Answer (score 0):

`player_info` is equal to the following expression (simplified a bit):

```
player_info = [[item for item in items] for items in content]
```

`content` seems to only have one item. What you want is probably something like:

```
 player_info = [item for item in content]
```

If content have more than one item, remove the second pair of `[ ... ]` in the first code block.